# How can I configure company-mode to only display candidates after an explicit keypress?

Tags: spacemacs, company-mode

I've configured the [Java layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/java) for my Spacemacs setup and am getting completion candidates using [company-mode](https://company-mode.github.io/) and the Eclim backend. However, everytime `company-complete` is triggered, I experience a short but noticable lag, which annoys me quite a bit.

Since I don't really *need* the autocompletion feature most of the time, I'd be glad if I can set up company mode in such a way that I have to trigger `company-complete` explicitly using a specific key binding (e.g. `C-SPC`, since that isn't really needed with `evil-mode` anyway).

I found no obvious candidate for this config option while browsing the `company-*` variables, and my Google fu hasn't turned up with any similar discussions so far. Just disabling `company-mode` using `SPC : company-mode` works, but triggering the completion using `M-x company-complete` during insert mode subsequently does nothing (except for printing a message that company was disabled). Same goes for toggling auto completion using `SPC t a`.

Comment: Does `company-idle-delay` look relevant?

Comment: Yes, setting `company-idle-delay` to `nil` seems to do the job. Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `company-idle-delay` to `nil`.

Quoting its docstring:

> The value of nil means no idle completion.